# Php has its own /tmp in /tmp/systemd-private-nABCDE/tmp when accessed through nginx

Tags: php, nginx, centos7, tmp

I found strange behaviour concerning `php` and `/tmp` folder. Php uses another folder when it works with `/tmp`. Php 5.6.7, nginx, php-fpm.

I execute the same script in two ways: via browser and via shell. But when it is launched via browser, file is not in real `/tmp` folder:

```
<?php
$name = date("His");

echo "File /tmp/$name.txt\n";

shell_exec('echo "123" > /tmp/'.$name.'.txt');

var_dump(file_exists('/tmp/'.$name.'.txt'));

var_dump(shell_exec('cat /etc/*release | tail -n 1'));
```

`php -f script.php`

```
File /tmp/185617.txt
bool(true)
string(38) "CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)
```

Where is the file? In /tmp

```
$ find / -name 185617.txt
/tmp/185617.txt
```

If access it via `http://myserver.ru/script.php` I get

```
File /tmp/185212.txt
bool(true)
string(38) "CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)
```

But where is the file?

```
$ find / -name 185212.txt
/tmp/systemd-private-nABCDE/tmp/185212.txt
```

Why does php thinks that `/tmp` should be in `/tmp/systemd-private-nABCDE/tmp`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Because [systemd is configured to give nginx a private /tmp](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/security.html). If you *must* use the system /tmp instead for some reason then you will need to modify the .service file to read "PrivateTmp=no".

Comment: You are right, but that's `php-fpm`, not `nginx`. I changed file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service` line `PrivateTmp=true` into `PrivateTmp=false`. Now php uses correct `/tmp` folder.

Comment: wow this is brilliant. right what we were searching since 2 days :)

Comment: Do consider the security implications of this change. `/tmp` may contain sensitive information and all php-scripts can suddenly access that information.

Comment: What if your system does not have the system sub folder? might it be somewhere else?

Comment: @Scott `find / -type f -name 'php-fpm.service'`. You'll need to run that as sudo/root most likely but it will recursively located any file starting from the root (/) directory that is named php-fpm.service.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running multiple sites on the server then I think you'll want to leave PrivateTmp=yes so that each site remains segregated even in it's use of temp files.  Could be a security issue otherwise, I'd imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams have the correct answer, but let me add my functional solution.

I've try "multi-user.target.wants" solution, it have worked but after restart, but at some point, PrivateTmp go back to true.
Like my principal use of Apache2 is PHP, I finally edited php.ini and I've uncomment line sys_temp_dir.

By default system use temp dir assigned by function sys_get_temp_dir. Function sys_get_temp_dir will return "/tmp" but the truth is that your tmp files are storing at some path like /tmp/systemd-private-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-apache2.service-YYYYYY//tmp/*. So, what work for me was:

Edit php.ini (path can change between PHP versions)

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
```

Then uncomment sys_temp_dir line

```
; Directory where the temporary files should be placed.
; Defaults to the system default (see sys_get_temp_dir)
sys_temp_dir = "/tmp"
```

Comment: The XXX can be read from `/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id` but from where do you get YYY?