# log_message is not working under application folder in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging

I have a Codeigniter application, in which I am logging the error, debug and info messages.
In config.php, I have set the threshold value as 4. I could see the log file in application/log folder. 
Now I tried to add a custom log from a method from a controller. I used

```
log_message("error", "this is my custom error");
```

But this is not logging in the log file. 
What I tried so far

- Changed the log file location
- Changed the log file permission
- Changed the level with 'debug', 'info'.
- Applied the changes in server files to see if it works in another server.

Nothing writing the log. 
In the existing log file, I can see the log messages from core files. I cannot write anything from the application folder.

Comment: Which web server and OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with Apache server.
I tried in Windows server as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For debugging update config.php as follows

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 4;
$config['log_path'] = '';
$config['log_file_extension'] = '';
$config['log_file_permissions'] = 0775;
```

In command line go to your 'application' folder using cd command

Try these commands

1. `sudo chgrp -R www-data logs/`
2. `sudo chmod -R 775 logs/`

Check log using controller.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. It was the issue of group permission I think.

Comment: Yeah .. default apache group name is www-data.. it needs write permission..

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is it possible for me to create a custom log file for a particular controller?

Comment: log_message("error", $this->router->fetch_class()." :this is my custom error"); will add controller name and will be easy to debug.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure your CI application/logs file has write permission by the web user.
2. Here are the relevant snippets from your application/config/config.php file:

   ```
    $config['log_threshold'] = 4;
    $config['log_path'] = '';
   ```
3. Restart your web server (e.g. "/etc/init.d/apache2 stop/start" for many versions of Linux.
4. if you're absolutely certain your log_message() is getting called, and you still don't see any entries in "application/logs", then consider changing log_path to a different path (e.g. /tmp, if only for troubleshooting purposes).
5. However, even "/tmp" isn't a Sure Thing.  Look at my post on how Systemd redirects PHP/Apache to a "private temp":

   [Why doesn't PHP 7.2 fopen(/tmp, a) write to the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55014399/421195)
6. Failing all else, the problem might be SELinux:

   [CentOS 7 + SELinux + PHP + Apache – cannot write/access file no matter what](https://blog.lysender.com/2015/07/centos-7-selinux-php-apache-cannot-writeaccess-file-no-matter-what/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Please find my comments on each point

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Please find my comments on each point
1) Logfile has write permission and it is writing. In my application I have log_message() called from core files. It is writing in log file. 
2) Correct
3) Restarted apache.
4) Actually, the log file is writing, but my concern is, when I add log_message() in my controller method, it is not writing. Still I changed the path.
5) 
6) I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with Apache